# How to lock drone at a desired height in Webots?

Tags: c, webots, pid-controller

I'm trying to use Webots software with C programming to simulate a quadcopter. For now, I just want my drone to be able to stay in a fixed position after take-off. Up to now, my drone was able to take off pretty well to the desired height but when it reached the desired height it started to lose balance and fall. I have tried to solve it by adjusting the P, D constants in my PD controllers but the drone all performed worse. So is it because the idea to code my drone to stay at a fixed altitude went wrong at some point? This is my code so far:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <webots/robot.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <webots/camera.h>
#include <webots/compass.h>
#include <webots/gps.h>
#include <webots/gyro.h>
#include <webots/inertial_unit.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <webots/led.h>
#include <webots/motor.h>


#define SIGN(x) ((x) > 0) - ((x) < 0)
#define CLAMP(value, low, high) ((value) < (low) ? (low) : ((value) > (high) ? (high) : (value)))

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  wb_robot_init();
  int timestep = (int)wb_robot_get_basic_time_step();

  // Get and enable devices.
  WbDeviceTag imu = wb_robot_get_device("inertial unit");
  wb_inertial_unit_enable(imu, timestep);
  WbDeviceTag gps = wb_robot_get_device("gps");
  wb_gps_enable(gps, timestep);
  WbDeviceTag compass = wb_robot_get_device("compass");
  wb_compass_enable(compass, timestep);
  WbDeviceTag gyro = wb_robot_get_device("gyro");
  wb_gyro_enable(gyro, timestep);
  WbDeviceTag camera = wb_robot_get_device("camera");
  wb_camera_enable(camera, timestep);
  WbDeviceTag camera_roll_motor = wb_robot_get_device("camera roll");
  WbDeviceTag camera_pitch_motor = wb_robot_get_device("camera pitch");
  

  // Get propeller motors and set them to velocity mode.
  WbDeviceTag front_left_motor = wb_robot_get_device("front left propeller");
  WbDeviceTag front_right_motor = wb_robot_get_device("front right propeller");
  WbDeviceTag rear_left_motor = wb_robot_get_device("rear left propeller");
  WbDeviceTag rear_right_motor = wb_robot_get_device("rear right propeller");
  WbDeviceTag motors[4] = {front_left_motor, front_right_motor, rear_left_motor, rear_right_motor};
  
  for (int i=0;i<4;++i) {
    wb_motor_set_position(motors[i], INFINITY);
    wb_motor_set_velocity(motors[i], 1.0);
  }

  

  // Wait one second.
  while (wb_robot_step(timestep) != -1) {
    if (wb_robot_get_time() > 1.0)
      break;
  }


  // Constants, empirically found.
  const double k_vertical_thrust = 68.5;  // with this thrust, the drone lifts.
  const double k_vertical_offset = 0.6;   // Vertical offset where the robot actually targets to stabilize itself.
 // const double k_vertical_p = 3.0;        // P constant of the vertical PID.
  const double k_roll_p = 50.0;           // P constant of the roll PID.
  const double k_pitch_p = 30.0;          // P constant of the pitch PID.

  // Set Point.
  double target_altitude = 1;  //also target y
  double target_x = 0.0;
  double target_z = 0.0;
  double target_yaw = -1;
     
  double Kp_x = 4.1; 
  double Kp_z = 1.0;
  double Kp_altitude = 2.0;
  double Kp_yaw = 0.0;
    
  double Kd_x = 1.0;
  double Kd_z = 1.0;
  double Kd_altitude = 8.1;
  double Kd_yaw = 0.0;
  
  double e_x=0;
  double last_e_x=0;
  double D_e_x=0;
  
  double e_z=0;
  double last_e_z=0;
  double D_e_z=0;
  
  double e_altitude=0;
  double last_e_altitude=0;
  double D_e_altitude=0;
  
  double e_yaw=0;
  double last_e_yaw=0;
  double D_e_yaw=0;
  
  double position_x=0;
  double altitude=0;
  double position_z=0;
  
  double pitch_input=0;
  double roll_input=0;
  double vertical_input=0;
  
  // Main loop
  while (wb_robot_step(timestep) != -1) {
    const double time = wb_robot_get_time();  // in seconds.
 
    // Retrieve robot position using the sensors.
    const double roll = wb_inertial_unit_get_roll_pitch_yaw(imu)[0] + M_PI / 2.0;
    const double pitch = wb_inertial_unit_get_roll_pitch_yaw(imu)[1];
    const double yaw= *wb_compass_get_values(compass);
    
    //const double altitude = wb_gps_get_values(gps)[1];
    const double roll_acceleration = wb_gyro_get_values(gyro)[0];
    const double pitch_acceleration = wb_gyro_get_values(gyro)[1];
    
    position_x = wb_gps_get_values(gps)[0];
    altitude = wb_gps_get_values(gps)[1];
    position_z = wb_gps_get_values(gps)[2];
 
    //PD controller for x position
    e_x=CLAMP(target_x + position_x, -1.0, 1.0);
    D_e_x= e_x- last_e_x;
    last_e_x=e_x;
    pitch_input=(k_pitch_p*CLAMP(pitch,-1.0,1.0))- 5*pitch_acceleration;
    pitch_input=pitch_input + (Kp_x*e_x) + (Kd_x*D_e_x);
     
     //PD controller for z position
    e_z=CLAMP(target_z - position_z, -1.0, 1.0);
    D_e_z= e_z - last_e_z;
    last_e_z= e_z;
    roll_input=(k_roll_p*CLAMP(roll,-1.0,1.0))+ 5*roll_acceleration;
    roll_input=roll_input + (Kp_z*e_z) + (Kd_z*D_e_z);
    
     //PD controller for altitude
    e_altitude=CLAMP(target_altitude - altitude + k_vertical_offset, -1.0, 1.0);
    D_e_altitude= e_altitude - last_e_altitude;
    last_e_altitude= e_altitude;
    vertical_input= (Kp_altitude*e_altitude) + (Kd_altitude*D_e_altitude);
    
     //PD controller for yaw(rotation)
    e_yaw= target_yaw - yaw;
    D_e_yaw= e_yaw - last_e_yaw;
    double yaw_input=Kp_yaw*CLAMP(e_yaw,-1.0,1.0) + Kd_yaw*D_e_yaw;
    last_e_yaw=e_yaw;
    

    // Stabilize the Camera by actuating the camera motors according to the gyro feedback.
    wb_motor_set_position(camera_roll_motor, -0.115 * roll_acceleration);
    wb_motor_set_position(camera_pitch_motor, -0.1 * pitch_acceleration);
 
    // Actuate the motors taking into consideration all the computed inputs.
     double front_left_motor_input = k_vertical_thrust + vertical_input - roll_input - pitch_input + yaw_input;
     double front_right_motor_input = k_vertical_thrust + vertical_input + roll_input - pitch_input - yaw_input;
     double rear_left_motor_input = k_vertical_thrust + vertical_input - roll_input + pitch_input - yaw_input;
     double rear_right_motor_input = k_vertical_thrust + vertical_input + roll_input + pitch_input + yaw_input;
    wb_motor_set_velocity(front_left_motor, front_left_motor_input);
    wb_motor_set_velocity(front_right_motor, -front_right_motor_input);
    wb_motor_set_velocity(rear_left_motor, -rear_left_motor_input);
    wb_motor_set_velocity(rear_right_motor, rear_right_motor_input);
```

Can someone help me point out my mistake and the way to fix this situation, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: That's a lot of code to review to find a "mistake". What seems to be the problem? Where do you think it is?

Comment: What this code *urgently* needs is functions, especially functions you can unit test to ensure they're performing correctly. Jamming everything in `main()` is not a sustainable development model.

Comment: I think this is less about programming problems and more about problems with calibrating a control-loop. At least that is how I read the question. I did not bother trying to find the code parts which match or contradict  that understanding. Please clarify explicitly.

Comment: I'm so sorry for posting a long piece of code because I can't figure out where it is wrong. I am wanting to lock my drone in a fix position and I have tried to do that by creating 6 P and PD controllers for (x,y) position, roll, pitch, yaw and altitude. I guess maybe in the code for those controllers, I used the wrong method somewhere so the drone becomes unbalanced when it gets to the position where it needs to be fixed.